# Load Javascript on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

How can I load this javascript modal on page load? It's from the plugin "sweet alert". I'm really bad with javascript. Any advice will surely help!

```
<script>
$(function () {

    $('.demo1').click(function(){
        swal({
            title: "Welcome in Alerts",
            text: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you use bootstrap?

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of information. What is swal()? Are you using a modal plugin? are you trying to roll your own modal?

Comment: @Soviut Im using "sweet alert"

Comment: so call it on page load, not click....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using jquery  you can use `document.ready` to wrap your code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.demo1').click(function() {
    swal({
      title: "Welcome in Alerts",
      text: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
    });
  });
})
</script>
```

Now if you are putting this snippets near the closing `body` you can avoid `document.ready`

```
<body>
   //rest of the dom element
   <script>
    $('.demo1').click(function() {
        swal({
          title: "Welcome in Alerts",
          text: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
        });
      });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `swal()` is what opens your modal, simply move it outside your click event. Your current code only runs the `swal()` function once the element with the `.demo1` class has been clicked. By moving it outside the click handler function, it gets run as soon as the page is ready.

```
$(function() {
    swal({
        title: 'welcome',
        text: 'ding!'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
 $('button').click(function(){
   swal("Oops! you clicked me.")
 })

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>



<button>Click me</button>
```

In-order to run the `sweetalert` you first need to call it's resources and also load the `jQuery` like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
$(function(){
  swal("Hi! I'm loaded on doc ready.");
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   swal({
  title: "Welcome in Alerts",
  text: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
   });
 });
</script>
```

just add this above script , this will trigger your sweet alert on the page load.